# Acroread save settings

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat

How can I get acroread to remember the printing settings I chosse? In particular, I set double sided printing each time and it forgets it next time.

Answer (score 1):

I found `acroread` to be unreliable when it comes to saving settings, though w.r.t. "double-sided printing" you may want to change your global printing preferences for your printer (e.g., look for "printing" in dash).

Alternatively, you may want to consider switching to a different pdf viewer like https://launchpad.net/~b-eltzner/+archive/qpdfview which is relatively new (up and coming) and, importantly, also support tabs.